# How to control Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab without the mouse

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Is it possible to control Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab without the mouse? I am looking for a way to navigate with the keyboard using Tab and the arrowkeys (or other keys). I know there are several keyboard shortcuts although this is not what I am looking for.

I have tried to run Jupyter lab as an application (on Windows) from this link:

http://christopherroach.com/articles/jupyterlab-desktop-app/

Although even then it is not possible to jump over the screen by Tab and the arrowkeys.

I also have tried Jupyter Lab 2.0 and 3.0. With these versions it is possible to move from File to Edit to View etc with the arrowkeys (see picture below), although it still needs a mouseclick to select File first. Besides that is is not possible to go from these menu items towards the buttons to the right (with Save, "+" and the scissors).

[image]

I hope there is a possibility!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JupyterLab team is currently working to improve accessibility, with a large focus on keyboard-only and screen reader-friendly navigation (see the [accessibility
meeting notes here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/team-compass/issues/98)). Hopefully the  changes will be included in upcoming 3.1 and 4.0 releases. You can contribute by testing these changes and taking part in the meetings or commenting on relevant GitHub issues.

As for opening menu without mouse, you need to create a shortcut for that (you can use the Advanced Settings Editor). The command for opening the file menu is `filemenu:open`. Please see the gif below:

[image]

Comment: @ krassowski Thanks a lot for your explanation and instructions how to add a shortcut to open the File-menu. I have just implemented it. I will experiment further with these personalized shortcuts. Great news that there is currently a project with focus on keyboard-only and screen reader-friendly navigation. I will folow the meetings. Thanks!